# Docker error in running postgres connection string (for SQLAlchemy) with sslmode

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a python app the connects to AWS RDS.

The connection string allows me to run the app in a Docker with no issues:

```
postgresql://<usr>:<pwd>@<svr>/<db>
```

The following 2 connection strings runs with the error below:

```
postgresql://<usr>:<pwd>@<svr>/<db>?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=xxx

postgresql://<usr>:<pwd>@<svr>/<db>?sslmode=require
```

Error (the bottom snippet):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
     response = self.handle_exception(e)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
     return original_handler(e)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
     return original_handler(e)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 458, in wrapper
     resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
     return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 573, in dispatch_request
     resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
   File "./database/database.py", line 29, in post
     database.save()
   File "./database/database.py", line 35, in save
     db.session.commit()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
     return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1026, in commit
     self.transaction.commit()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 493, in commit
     self._prepare_impl()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 472, in _prepare_impl
     self.session.flush()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2451, in flush
     self._flush(objects)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2589, in _flush
     transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
     compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 129, in reraise
     raise value
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2549, in _flush
     flush_context.execute()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
     rec.execute(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
     uow,
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 213, in save_obj
     ) in _organize_states_for_save(base_mapper, states, uowtransaction):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 374, in _organize_states_for_save
     base_mapper, uowtransaction, states
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1585, in _connections_for_states
     connection = uowtransaction.transaction.connection(base_mapper)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 312, in connection
     return self._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 418, in _connection_for_bind
     conn = self._parent._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 430, in _connection_for_bind
     conn = bind._contextual_connect()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2226, in _contextual_connect
     self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2266, in _wrap_pool_connect
     e, dialect, self
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1536, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
     util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 128, in reraise
     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2262, in _wrap_pool_connect
     return fn()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 354, in connect
     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 751, in _checkout
     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 483, in checkout
     rec = pool._do_get()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 138, in _do_get
     self._dec_overflow()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
     compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 129, in reraise
     raise value
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 135, in _do_get
     return self._create_connection()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 299, in _create_connection
     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 428, in __init__
     self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 630, in __connect
     connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 453, in connect
     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not create SSL context: library has no ciphers
```

When I run with all 3 connection types, it works on all machines except Docker. Is there a reason why this is happening only in a Docker?

**I forgot to state, I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to postgresql.**

Thank you.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.2-stretch

COPY . /

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR /models

CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini"]
```

My docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  modelling:
    build:
      context: ./modelling
    image: users-api
    container_name: modelling
    ports:
        - 5000:5000
    restart: always
```

My requirements:

```
aniso8601==6.0.0
argon2-cffi==19.1.0
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.1.0
cffi==1.12.2
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.18.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
more-itertools==7.0.0
pluggy==0.9.0
psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
py==1.8.0
pycparser==2.19
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytest==4.3.1
pytz==2018.9
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.1
uWSGI==2.0.18
Werkzeug==0.15.1
```

Comment: Can you add content of your requrements.yml to question?

Comment: @sergkondr I've added my requirements. Also I'm using SLQAlchemy.

Comment: I am currently experiencing this issue. I don't know if anyone has a fix out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change following string in your requirements.txt:

```
psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
```

to

```
psycopg2==2.7.7 --no-binary :all:
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Would you mind explaining what's the difference in the two? Because when I use psycopg2, it always has an error stating to use psycopg2-binary. Something about psycopg2 not going to be updated or something.

Comment: Also is seems that I can't use this in my IDE, when I pip install psycopg2==2.7.7 --no-binary :all:, is says pgconfig is needed to build. Do you know why? This isn't an issue, just curious, I can use psycopg2-binary==2.7.7 in my IDE but change it when I do a Docker.

Comment: The difference is described in the issue: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1569